# Can't get composer "path" repository to work

Tags: php, json, repository, package, composer-php

I have a directory structure like so:

```
composer.json < Main
  packages/
    balunker/
      testpackage/
        composer.json < Package
        src/
          TestPackage.php
```

The main `composer.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "vagrant/composer-test",
    "repositories": [
        {
             "type": "path",
            "url": "packages/*/*"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "balunker/testpackage": "*"
    }
}
```

While the package `composer.json` looks like so:

```
{
  "name": "balunker/testpackage",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Balunker\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

On `composer update` I simple get a message that the package could not be resolved. No symlinks are created and no package is installed. I have literally spent half of my day figuring this out, without any success.

I also uploaded a `composer update -vvv` verbose output of this: http://pastebin.com/mMRHsACk.

My composer version is the latest (as of 20th of April 2016 at 2:39pm UTC) and all of this is running inside Vagrant (Debian).

ANY recommendation from hereon is greatly appreciated. I really don't know what else to do any more.

Answer (score 87):

I posted the issue on Github as well and it turns out that the documentation is a little misleading. It says:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../packages/my-package"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package": "*"
    }
}
```

However, if you just have a local repo without releases, you have to use:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../packages/my-package"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

The version `dev-master` is the key here (given that you are working on the master branch). This was mildly infuriating, but thanks to some helpful composer contributors, I could finally get a grip on this.

Comment: For me, the trick was to add [`"minimum-stability": "dev"`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) to my composer.json file

Comment: @BradKent I would highly discourage from from using the `"minimum-stability": "dev"` thing as it means: You want from all dependencies the latest unstable version. The `dev-` prefix or `-dev` suffix will only change this for the one package in question.

Comment: As long as you also have `"prefer-stable": true`, you're fine.  It will only use dev packages when necessary to satisfy a dependency.

Comment: As an alternative to setting the whole composer to `minimum-stability: dev` you can flag individual packages that way via `dev-master` or `*@dev` for the version. For anyone running this on Windows, you may also need to add `{"options": { "symlink": false }}` to the repository definition so that you switch from junctioning to mirroring the local package.

Comment: I've tried all solutions posted on stack and still nothing

Comment: Finally. this solved my issue for being able to install LaRecipe in laravel.

Comment: This has a classic issue with recursive repositories definition if such 2 libraries would be dependant, "nested" and needed redefining not only repositories but also all the nested dependencies, plus  once the same library exist on packagist it would not work and the package name field would have to be renamed. Plus it finds out the version for stability only from the explicit version definition in the file, not from the local git tags, as in that case, it does have access to define version from tags from Github.

Answer (score 10):

For me the problem was that I forget to mount the repository folder with docker, so the local webserver could not reach it. Pay attention for that as well

Comment: Example, in the `docker-compose.yml`: `volumes: - ~/projects/my-package:~/projects/my-package` (reformat to make it syntactically correct).

Comment: Man...thanks! I totally forgot this point :')

Answer (score 8):

What helped me resolve was `composer clear-cache` and then running `composer update`.

**Explanation:** I had initially tried to `composer install my/package` which failed on dependency versions. So I needed to make some local modifications to make it work with Laravel 6.0. However, it continued checking for the wrong version of Laravel packages which led me to believe it was not seeing my local repository which I set in the `repositories` key with `"type": "path"`. I first ensured the path existed and I was on the correct branch (`master` which is why I use `dev-master` in my `composer.json`). Once I cleared the composer cache and ran the update it updated using my local path with no dependency issues.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../libs/package-name"
    }
],
"require-dev": {
    "pkg-maintainer/package-name": "dev-master"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was very similar to the above, but I had to specifically target the branch I was developing on.

Assuming code in directory /newapp on the same level as /app, and a branch named feature/the-new-package:

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "path",
    "url": "newapp"
  }
],
"require": {
  "package/newapp": "dev-feature/the-new-package"
},
```

\* did not work, neither did dev-master. It had to be dev-feature/the-new-package.

Answer (score 2):

For future Googlers, add your version to the `composer.json` and then require the package with the `--prefer-source` option.

For example: `composer require your-vendor/package:1.0.* --prefer-source`

Answer (score 2):

Composer seems to get confused if the package is already installed from the original repository: it fetches your local repo and refreshes *composer.lock* from its *composer.json* but doesn't even try to fetch changes into vendor directory.

Removing it first seems to address it:

```
composer remove foo/bar
composer require foo/bar @dev
```

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case my problem was the repository priorities, "When Composer resolves dependencies, it will look up a given package in the topmost repository", check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/repository-priorities.md
TLDR; in composer.json make sure your local path goes first under respositories

```
"repositories": [
    {
         "type": "path",
         "url": "packages/local-path-goes-first"
    },
    {
         "type": "vcs",
         "url": "https://github.com/berrugo/other-repos"
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `"minimum-stablilty": "dev"` was key to getting my local package to install correctly.

This format also works quite well for me; it not only states the package name, but it's clean and easy to read.

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"repositories": {
    "foo/bar": {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "/Users/username/Sites/packages/packageName",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
}
```