# How to use path type local repository with Composer

Tags: dependencies, composer-php

I am relatively new to Composer and have been looking for an example of using a local repository using the path repo type.  I've found several articles (e.g. [this one](http://file:///home/cfe/projects/composer-test/app1/composer.json) and [this one](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/doc/05-repositories.md) on the topic, but when I try the examples I end up getting an error like:

```
The requested package myvendor/mylibrary could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

So I thought I'd create a super-simple example of what I'm trying in hopes that someone can point me in the right direction.

My sample app is organised as such:

```
├── app1
│   └── composer.json
├── app2
│   └── composer.json
└── libraries
    └── testlibrary
        ├── composer.json
        ├── TestService.php
```

Within `libraries/testlibrary/composer.json` is the following:

```
{
  "name": "myvendor/mylibrary",
  "version": "dev-master"
}
```

And within each of the app folders (e.g. app1) the `composer.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../libraries/testlibrary"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "myvendor/mylibrary": "*"
    }
}
```

If anyone has any suggestion for what I'm doing incorrectly, I'd be very appreciative!

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745691/cant-get-composer-path-repository-to-work)

Instead of this:

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../packages/my-package"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package": "*"
    }
}
```

You should write this:

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../packages/my-package"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Note the change from `*` to `dev-master` in the `require` section.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks correct. I use that solution as well. I think the problem lies elsewhere. Try changing `*` constraint to something like `dev-master`. If that doesn't solve it, please post your `composer.json` from `mylibrary`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried changing the "dev-master" to "*" in mylibrary's composer.json file, but the one using path doesn't work still.

Comment: Would it be possible to see an example of how your composer.json files are set up?  Maybe I can learn from your example.

Comment: I don't think you need that `"version": "dev-master"` in composer.json

Comment: I removed that but it didn't affect the project with the compoer.json file that uses path.  If anyone has a working example of how to use composer to share a file by using path - and not using psr-0 - I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Yup, I'm out of ideas for this one.