# Laravel package inside a package not showing my routes

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a Laravel 8 project that includes a custom built package called `pkg-inbound-management`. It's included in my project's root composer file and this package includes a bunch of routes.

I've extended the package to include a new **packages** folder with a new mini custom package and have included it into the main package's composer file via the `repositories` section.

The issue I'm facing is that when I run `php artisan route:list` in my project which includes the package, I don't see the package's package routes. and would like to know what I'm missing.

**pkg-inbound-management**

```json
{
    "name": "company/pkg-inbound-management",
    "description": "Laravel package for integrating inbound logic into a website",
    "type": "library",
    "version": "1.8.0",
    "keywords": [
        "company",
        "inbounds"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "company",
            "email": "contact@company.co.uk"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./packages/fudge-pkg-inbound-management-bridge"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "Company\\InboundManagement\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Company\\InboundManagement\\InboundManagementServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This package then includes the following:

```json
{
    "name": "company/fudge-pkg-inbound-management-bridge",
    "description": "Fudge Inbound Management Bridge",
    "type": "library",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4|^8.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Company\\FudgePkgInboundManagementBridge\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Company\\FudgePkgInboundManagementBridge\\FudgePkgInboundManagementBridgeServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a visualisation of the structure:

[image]

The main package, **pkg-inbound-management** is then included into my project which is where the routes from the bridge package appear to not show up.

Comment: I think Laravel is Autoloading the Service Provider. (which will be autoloaded by your composer hook) So you need to provider your own too Provider and load it manually

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: Tried this thanks, but isn't working, think the package inside the package isn't being loaded

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -3):

Assumption the package installed correctly.

You may have your routes cached and need to clear the cache. You can run `php artisan route:cache` to refresh the cache.

Comment: Already tried this, I believe the package may not be loaded into the package.

Comment: Ah, you can refer to the issue in the ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745691/cant-get-composer-path-repository-to-work
I think it will help you